# Python deadlock related to packaging and mayavi?

Tags: python, multithreading, packaging, mayavi

I have a curious problem that I hope someone can shed some light on.

I have a complex piece of code, that started as a directory full of scripts, that I decided to rework into a package. This code change appears to have been the trigger for some strange deadlocks to appear.

Below is an attempt at canonical reproduction of the problem; which fails, in the sense that this code runs as expected. Actually reproducing the issue may require a lot of code; but I cannot for the life of my imagine what is different for the offending code snippet in-context.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from threading import Thread

def dummy():
    print 'this is printed'
    I = np.eye(3)
    print 'all is still fine'
    csr_matrix(I)
    print 'this is never printed; csr_matrix appears to be a trigger for deadlock'
    print np.ones(4)
    print 'same problem; somehow, printing ndarrays is no longer cool either'

thr = Thread(target=dummy)
thr.start()
```

Perhaps this terse comment in the docs is related? I am not sure I fully appreciate what is being said here

http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading#importing-in-threaded-code

*Firstly, other than in the main module, an import should not have the side effect of spawning a new thread and then waiting for that thread in any way. Failing to abide by this restriction can lead to a deadlock if the spawned thread directly or indirectly attempts to import a module.*

Some context: I am using python 2.7, numpy 1.8, where I try to spawn this new thread from within a mayavi/traitsui thread (which I dont see why it should be relevant, and which worked fine before the package structure, but ok). Also, there is a boatload of numpy/scipy code in my spawned thread that executes perfectly fine; its just printing ndarrays and creating sparse matrices which so far have proven to be triggers for deadlock.

I am suspecting some funky interaction with mayavi, since closing the mayavi window causes all deadlocked threads to start running again. Perhaps these specific statement trigger the python thread to yield back to the mayavi thread, but they somehow fail to gain focus again?

Any hints that lead to further narrowing down on this mystery are much appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to say, since the problem is probably related to details of your code that you have not reproduced here. Are you `join()`ing any of these threads? Are you starting them at the top level of the module as in the example that you gave us? If you are doing both of those things, then that is what that comment from the documentation is telling you not to do. There is a global import lock that is held while the code of a module is being executed. Calling `csr_matrix()` that way does cause an import, so it will also try to acquire the import lock. Deadlock ensues. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is how I understood the docs; but I am doing neither of those things. I am not joining anything anywhere. Perhaps mayavi does somewhere behind the scenes; but that's not what the docs warn about, no? The thread is started from a method in a UI object, as a response to user input. Also, csr_matrix has long since been imported elsewhere at this point; it should be cached, so does the import lock still come into play?

Comment: Also; any clues as to what makes csr_matrix and ndarray.__repr__ special? Why does my thread march happily through code going all over the place; numpy scipy and a whole slew of imports, but gets consistently stuck no matter where I invoke either of these two functions?

Comment: Calling `csr_matrix()` on a dense `ndarray` [causes an import](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/compressed.py#L64). If you can come up with a complete example that demonstrates the problem, I may be able to help.

Comment: When you say you are using Mayavi, do you mean that you are using `mlab.show()` in your script as opposed to integrating your code into the Mayavi application?

Comment: But what is special about this import? There must be literally 100's of imports going on in my code that do not cause problems.

I am using an MlabSceneModel instance from within a traited class. I used to configure_traits() this traited class from __main__, starting the main backend thread, but since refactoring my project to a package, this no longer occurs in __main__, but in a module import-ed from main. This may some bearing on the situation.

Comment: Ah; calling configure_traits from what now is the new __main__ solves the problem. Also, putting the configure_traits() call inside a dummy function rather than directly in the module solves the problem (in a more elegant way). Apparently this is a mayavi bug, or atleast gotcha. Again, im not the one doing any joining of threads anywhere, and all the mayavi examples happily advocate putting configure_traits on the module level. Im still lost as to what makes csr_matrix and ndarray.__repr__ special; but at least things are working again, which is a start. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The mayavi examples show scripts to be executed, not modules to be imported.

Comment: It is somewhat unpythonic that what should be a mere organizational affair can have such make and break consequences, though.

Comment: Ypu are right though; its not a mayavi bug. Just a gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like you start up the UI event loop at the top level of one of your subsidiary modules. This is not a good idea because it causes exactly the same problems that the documentation alludes to. `import foo` should never start a UI event loop. The problem is that the main thread grabs the import lock to handle the import of the module. This module starts up the UI event loop before completing the import. This is essentially the same situation as the waiting for the other threads to finish; you are waiting for the UI loop to finish. If your UI starts up other threads, the code that is running in the other threads will not be able to import anything (both `csr_matrix()` and `ndarray.__repr__()` import other modules) because the main thread is still holding onto the import lock.

Comment: I see; configure_traits both creates a thread, and then waits for it, which is against the rules as specified in the docs (wouldn't hurt if the mayavi docs emphasized this). However, what I don't get is that deadlock only occurs when using a very narrow subset of functions (again, tons of code littered with imports executes without trouble, both in the mayavi thread as in its child).

Comment: I still cant say I fully grasp what is going on here, and I must say I am somewhat disappointed in the pythonicity of it all. But despite that, carefully reading the docs and sticking to them does solve the issue. Thanks for the back and forth; even though I figured it out eventually, ill accept this as an answer.

Comment: `configure_traits()` does not create a thread. It just runs the UI loop and does not return until the UI loop completes. All UI loops behave like this. [The documentation of `configure_traits()`](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/has_traits.html#traits.has_traits.HasTraits.configure_traits) tells you this. I expect none of the threads you are using actually import things *inside* the thread like calling `csr_matrix()` or `ndarray.__repr__()` do, just using modules that were imported into the module namespace before the thread started.

Comment: I was under the impression that all traits applications used multiple threads internally? But regardless; the call to configure_traits() is blocking, so my worker thread is still indirectly a side effect of the import, so the import lock is still in-place.

Comment: But if configure_traits() does not create a thread, doesn't that make the docs incomplete? The trouble is supposed to result from creating a thread at module level and then joining it. But again; im not waiting for any threads. If mayavi/traits doesn't either, what gives? Id say the warning in the docs isn't general enough; not just joining threads is to be avoided, but any kind of blocking code, like a UI loop will cause trouble. That's implied once you understand whats going on; but I almost decided this caveat had no relevance to me because I wasn't joining any threads anywhere anyway!

Comment: I think that as Robert Kern suggests your problem has nothing to do with mayavi in this case.  However, because of how precisely mayavi needs to manage its scenes, there are still a lot of "bugs" that are not bugs (and maybe a couple of real bugs as well) with mayavi when your GUI gets complicated and tries to do lots of things with threads.  Generally, to build GUI applications around mayavi it is often necessary to manage the order in which things occur explicitly.

That is to say, I think it is a good idea to take any documentation caveat about blocking as inherently relevant to mayavi.